# Looking for a sample that uses the Direct Linear Transform on images

Tags: image-processing

Where can I find :
"Direct Linear Transform" algorithm (and the method to compute homography matrix) coded in Java/C++/C#/C ?

Answer (score -1):

From Wikipedia:

[OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) is a complete (open and free) computer vision software library that has many routines related to homography estimation ([findHomography](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography))

Comment: `findHomography` does not implement DLT. It finds a homography between two planar images. [`solvePnP`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnp) would be closer to the mark, but also doesn't implement the DLT because it assumes that the camera's intrinsic parameters are known.